# Multiport NIC forgets Static IP

Tags: windows-10, subnet, static-ip, wired-networking, crossover-cable

Kind of a niche use here, but I'm using multiple PC's to host virtual instruments via network and stream audio back to the primary machine's DAW. Best case scenario is that the host and slave machines have their own connection via crossover - and since I was running into issues with bandwidth being limited on the primary machine I decided to learn some *very* caveman level ip scheming/subnetting. As a result I've got a pair of these: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0C4H23NMT?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C4H23NMT) and each machine access the internet via wifi, but has a crossover to the main machine.

I've used a subnet mask of 255.255.255.252, and the default gateway is the 'other' machine in each subnet. If I remove the default gateway they'll show up as an unrecognized network and seem to perform worse - but the problem I have persists regardless;

When I restart, it seems to randomly 'forget' 1 or 2 static IP configurations. It'll sometimes even jumble the names of the connections. At this point it's a minor issue, as it seems to really only be a problem on my main machine. Takes maybe a minute or two to unplug the ethernet out of the computer it's not connecting to anymore and it'll update which connection is unplugged and I can just fix the IP configs. Doesn't seem to be consistently a particular port - and not consistently the same 4 port NIC card either.

there is no DCHP reservation that I'm aware of using a crossover with no access point/router involved. I've considered disabling ipv6/every other protocol outside of tcp/udp/ipv4 -- is there another setting that is hiding somewhere that is causing some shuffling on reboot? Would I have better luck digging in the registry for assignments instead of using windows 10's network adapter properties?

Comment: To start with, do you actually *need* dedicated ports for each device, rather than a standard 1Gbps NIC going to an Ethernet switch? You mentioned bandwidth being limited, but... it seems like you'd need well over 500+ audio channels to even come close to saturating a 1Gbps interface. (My initial guess is that the manufacturer just didn't do a good job at adapting the RTL8111H drivers to detect all four chips in the correct order so the OS can't tell which port is which...)

Comment: Well that's a common mistake. 1gbe is not 1 gigabyte per second, it's 1 gigabit so you'll top out about an 8th of what you'd expect. Due to the nature of latency and trying to play instruments in real time, you're lucky not to get dropouts at about 70-80 mb/sec in task manager. Each machine can easily saturate this, as 16 midi ports = 16 instruments, sending 8 ch 48k(4 stereo mic signals)       That said, at this point unless there is another setting that occasionally interferes, I'm going to assume it's the drivers on this nic